# Angular unit test with httpclient

Tags: angular, unit-testing, http, httpclient

I have the following function and I would like to do a unit test on it. Or how to mock the httpclient

```
export function TranslateFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslationService(http, 'assets/i18n');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading the [Testing HTTP Services](https://angular.io/guide/testing-services#testing-http-services) from the Angular documentation and then going from there.

Comment: This function is not in a service but in theModuleapp. I use it in factory mode to load my translations. Can I have an example please?

Comment: If I'm going to be able to help you I need more context, you're going to have to try and provide some kind of source code and/or stackblitz so that we can see this in action. Could you please provide me with a stackblitz of your app so that so that I can help you out?